# Not able to print simple fibonacci series in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to print simple fibonacci series in Komodo using Python.

but not getting any o/p

Can someone explain me the mistake.

I'm starting to learn Python. please let me know from where to start. Any link to full python course.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Copyright 2009-2017 BHG http://bw.org/

# simple fibonacci series
# the sum of two elements defines the next set
def feb(a,b):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < 1000:
        print(b, end = ' ', flush = True)
    a, b = b, a + b
    print()
```

Comment: You need:to call your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't call your function. Just call it and also remove parameters as you already assigned them inside your body.

make following changes in your code

```
def feb():
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < 1000:
        print(b, end = ' ', flush = True)
    a, b = b, a + b
feb()
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indent correctly and you need to call your function. Also there is no need for a and b to be passed as arguments

Something like this:

```
def feb():
  a, b = 0, 1
  while b < 1000:
    print(b)
    a, b = b, a + b

feb()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call your function. Also if you are passing variables in function definition, they should be defined outside the function and then must be referenced in function call .

```
a, b = 0, 1
def feb(a, b):
    while b < 1000:
        print(b, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b 
        
feb(a, b)
```

Comment: Just calling `feb(0,1)` would make even more sense, IMHO. Global variables should be avoided if possible.